# Artwork from ending of Monster?

Tags: monster

In the first ending song of Monster, what is the significance of the artwork and who made it?

**Important: I am only halfway through Monster. Please no spoilers!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is going to be all spoilers.

> Those are pictures are from the book [Obluda, Která Nemá Své
>  Jméno](http://obluda.wikia.com/wiki/Obluda) or "A monster without a
>  name" by Franz Bonaparta under the alias Emil Scherbe in the Czech
>  language. It was first introduced in the anime at episode 37 and in
>  chapter 71 in the manga.
>
>  Though the book itself is created by a fictional character from Monster, I believe you can actually buy a real copy of it.
>
>  See also: [The nameless monster article](http://www.fanpop.com/clubs/anime/articles/142586/title/nameless-monster).